# Dartium fails to launch on LMDE

Tags: linux, dart, glibc, dartium

I'm running Linux Mint Debian Edition, and Dartium fails to launch due to outdated glibc (I have glibc-2.13-1) the exact message I get is this:

```
./chrome: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by ./chrome)
./chrome: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by ./chrome)
```

What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Not -sure either updating the system or try to build dartium from source but there might a reason why they require a newer version.

Here is a discussion on how to update to a new libc without updating the system:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62940/how-to-run-new-software-without-updating-glibc